# PHP Frontend and Rest API + OAuth, detect third party app

Tags: php, oauth

I'm building a Rest API and a frontend written in PHP.

My question is that I intent to protect it with OAuth when third-party apps try to access it.
But I don't want to use OAuth when my frontend uses the API.
How can I detect/identify when an APP that is not my frontend is trying to access my API.

What's is the best strategy?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your frontend public or private code?

Comment: Private. What I really want is that my frontend does not require a complex authentication like oauth... so i would like to identify when the request if from my frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways that you can go about this:

You can perhaps give the API an alias only used by the frontend server and utilize a different authentication mechanism (i.e. keyed access) for that API alias.

You could set a specific custom request header that is only used by the frontend server and use your alternate authentication mechanism when that header is present.

You can pass along some additional data with the requests that identify the request as coming from your frontend server.

I personally would opt for one of the first two, as I wouldn't want to change the data structure unnecessarily.

Comment: Upvote, I'd say the easiest header to set and consume would be the User Agent.

Comment: Yes, I'm using this approach now. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

Generate token and check if it exists.